# Relative path in Python

Tags: python

I'm writing some python code to generate the relative path. Situation need to be considered:

1. Under the same folder. I want "." or ".\", both of tham are ok for me.
2. Other folder. I want like ".\xxx\" and "..\xxx\xxx\"

os.path.relpath() will generate the relative path, but without .\ at the beginning and \ in the end. We can add \ in the end by using os.path.join(dirname, ""). But i can't figure out how to add ".\" at the beginning without impacting the first case when they are under the same folder and "..\xxx\xxx\".

Comment: Backslashes?? Ah, a windows user...

Answer (score 0):

It will give you relative path

```
import os
dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
filename = os.path.join(dir,'Path')
```

Answer (score 0):

The relpath() function will produce the ".." syntax given the appropriate base to start from (second parameter). For instance, supposing you were writing something like a script generator that produces code using relative paths, if the working directory is as the second parameter to relpath() as below indicates, and you want to reference in your code another file in your project under a directory one level up and two deep, you'll get "../blah/blah".. In the case where you want to prefix paths in the same folder, you can simply do a join with ".". That will produce a path with the correct OS specific separator.

```
print(os.path.relpath("/foo/bar/blah/blah", "/foo/bar/baz"))
>>> ../blah/blah

print(os.path.join('.', 'blah'))
>>> ./blah
```

Comment: Provide more contents to support your answer, adding merely a code snippet doesn't seems to be a good answer.

Comment: I thought it was pretty self-evident, but anyway, the relpath() function will produce the ".." syntax given the appropriate base to start from (second parameter).  For instance, if the working directory is as the second parameter indicates, and you want to reference in your code another file in your project under a directory one level up and two deep, you'll get "../blah/blah"..  In the case where you want to prefix paths in the same folder, you can simply do a join with ".".  That will produce a path with the correct OS specific separator.

Comment: Write it in your answer ;)